# Typescript: Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, promise

I'm building a table using material-table. Here is an example of how the table should be built: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/filtering

I'm trying to pass an array in the `data` to populate the fields from the my `Userlist` array.

I have this in my `componentDidMount()` function

```
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Team").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
        //console.log(items); 
        const UserList = items.map((item) => {

            return {
                UsersName: item.Title,
                UserEmail: item.Email_x0020_Address,
                UserStatus: item.Status,
                UserLocation: item.Location,
                UserAdditional: item.Additional,                        
            }
        });
        //console.log(UserList);

        this.setState({ UserList: [...UserList] });

    });
```

In my render I have this:

```
        <MaterialTable
            title=""
            columns={[
            { title: 'Name', field: 'UsersName' },
            { title: 'Email', field: 'UserEmail' },
            { title: 'Status', field: 'UserStatus' },
            { title: 'Location', field: 'UserLocation' },                   
            { title: 'Additional', field: 'UserAdditional' },
            ]}
            data={new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                (this.state.UserList)
            })}       
            options={{
            filtering: true
            }}
        />
```

Initially I had `data={this.state.Userlist}` but was getting a `_this.props.data is not a function at MaterialTable` error.

So I changed, so I passed the data in a promise to bypass the error but am now getting this error:

```
 error TS2322: Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type '({ UsersName: any; } & { UserEmail: any; } & { UserStatus: any; } & { UserLocation: any; } & { UserAdditional: any; })[] | ((query: Query<{ UsersName: any; } & { UserEmail: any; } & { UserStatus: any; } & { UserLocation: any; } & { ...; }>) => Promise<...>)'.
```

Comment: What do you expect the Promise to do? I'm a little confused by that. According to [the docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) it seems that `data` should be an array or a function that returns the data. I'm guessing your array is missing at first?

Comment: Could be as simple as `data={this.state.data || []}` or defaulting your initial state to an empty array? But I can only guess with limited info

Comment: @Brian Thompson so when i change it to `data={this.state.UserList || []}` i get the ` TypeError: _this.props.data is not a function
    at MaterialTable.` error

Comment: I also did a `{JSON.stringify(this.state.UserList)}` and all the elements are in the array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423419/passing-asynchronously-acquired-data-to-child-props

Comment: @Supercool. thanks for the help. I think you're right. It looks like the table gets rendered before the data gets passed in. I'm still a little confused on how to fix it using the link you sent.. I tried moving the function to `componentWillMount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have vast knowledge of ReactJS basically I'm Angular guy but on searching I found this.

Execution Flow:

[image: Order of execution in react]

**Method 1:**

Change the method from componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount because componentWillMount was deprecated in 2018.More here https://dev.to/torianne02/componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-5f0n

```
UNSAFE_componentWillMount()
{
 this.setState({ UserList: [] });
  pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Team").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
    //console.log(items); 
    const UserList = items.map((item) => {

        return {
            UsersName: item.Title,
            UserEmail: item.Email_x0020_Address,
            UserStatus: item.Status,
            UserLocation: item.Location,
            UserAdditional: item.Additional,                        
        }
    });
    //console.log(UserList);

    this.setState({ UserList: [...UserList] });
});
}
```

Method2: 
In the constructor initialize the state:

```
constructor() {
    // Required step: always call the parent class' constructor
    super(props);

    // Set the state directly. 
    this.state = {
        UserList: [],
        //if you have any other state variables add here
    }
  }
```

Do the get call in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Team").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
        //console.log(items); 
        const UserList = items.map((item) => {

            return {
                UsersName: item.Title,
                UserEmail: item.Email_x0020_Address,
                UserStatus: item.Status,
                UserLocation: item.Location,
                UserAdditional: item.Additional,                        
            }
        });
        //console.log(UserList);

        this.setState({ UserList: [...UserList] });
    })
}
```

Render function in both cases

```
render(){
   return ( <MaterialTable
   title=""
   columns={[
   { title: 'Name', field: 'UsersName' },
   { title: 'Email', field: 'UserEmail' },
   { title: 'Status', field: 'UserStatus' },
   { title: 'Location', field: 'UserLocation' },                   
   { title: 'Additional', field: 'UserAdditional' },
   ]}
   data={this.state.Userlist}      
   options={{
   filtering: true
   }}
/>)
}
```

Comment: Enjoy the day bro!